# Edit record page in Mysql and PHP "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'linkyoutube'"

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am trying to create a page to edit records from my database. I build the page and when I try to submit the changes I receive an error that the " Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'linkyoutube'". I have checked the database to make sure the admin user has the permissions necessary to update the table. I am not sure what else to check any help is appreciated.

code for edit page:

```
<?php
//require "admin_login.php";
//include "admin_connect.php"
          $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", 
            "admin9090", "linkyoutube");
          mysql_select_db("linkyoutube");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
          echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . 
              mysqli_connect_error($conn);
            }
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = "select * from submited left join person on person.person_id=submited.person_id where person.person_id= $_GET[id];";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ;

        }

?>
<h1>Modifying Record</h1>


                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="Form1" method="post"  onSubmit="return validateForm();">
                <p>First Name:      <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>" size="60"></p>
                <p>Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>" size="60"></p>
                <p>Email:      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" size="60"></p>
                <p>Telephone: <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Eg. +447000 000000" value="<?php echo $row['telephone']; ?>" required></p>
                <p>Address:    <input type="text" textarea name="address" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></p>
                <p>Select a State   <select id="state" type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['state']; ?>" >
                                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                                    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                                    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                                    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                                    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
                                    </select></p>
                <p>Select a Country <select id="country"  name="country" value="<?php echo $row['country']; ?>">                  
                                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                                    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                                    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                                    <option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
                                    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                                    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                                    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                                    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                                    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                                    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                                    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                                    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                                    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                                    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                                    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                                    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                                    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                                    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                                    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                                    <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
                                    <option value="Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
                                    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                                    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                                    <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
                                    <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                                    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                                    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                                    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                                    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                                    <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                                    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                                    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                                    <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                                    <option value="China">China</option>
                                    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                                    <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
                                    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                                    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                                    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                                    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                                    <option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
                                    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                                    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                                    <option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
                                    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                                    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                                    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                                    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                                    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                                    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                                    <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
                                    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                                    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                                    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                                    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                                    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                                    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                                    <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                                    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                                    <option value="France">France</option>
                                    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                                    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                                    <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
                                    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                                    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                                    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                                    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                                    <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
                                    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                                    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                                    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                                    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                                    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                                    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                                    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                                    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                                    <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                                    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                                    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                                    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                                    <option value="India">India</option>
                                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                    <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
                                    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                                    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                                    <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
                                    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                                    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                                    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                                    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                                    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                                    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                                    <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
                                    <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
                                    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                                    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                    <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
                                    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                                    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                                    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                                    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                                    <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                                    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                                    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                                    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                                    <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                                    <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                                    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                                    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                                    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                                    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                                    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                                    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                                    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                                    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                                    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                                    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                                    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                                    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                                    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                                    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                                    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                                    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                                    <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
                                    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                                    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                                    <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
                                    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
                                    <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
                                    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                                    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                                    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                                    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                                    <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                                    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                                    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                                    <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
                                    <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
                                    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                                    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                                    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                                    <option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
                                    <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
                                    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                                    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                                    <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                                    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                                    <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
                                    <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
                                    <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                                    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                                    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                                    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                                    <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
                                    <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
                                    <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
                                    <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
                                    <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
                                    <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
                                    <option value="St Pierre &amp; Miquelon">St Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
                                    <option value="St Vincent &amp; Grenadines">St Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
                                    <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
                                    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                                    <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
                                    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                                    <option value="Sao Tome &amp; Principe">Sao Tome &amp; Principe</option>
                                    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                                    <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                                    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                                    <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                                    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                                    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                                    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                                    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                                    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                                    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                                    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                                    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                                    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                                    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                                    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                                    <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
                                    <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
                                    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                                    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                                    <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                                    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                                    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                                    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                                    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                                    <option value="Trinidad &amp; Tobago">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
                                    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                                    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                                    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                                    <option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Is">Turks &amp; Caicos Is</option>
                                    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                                    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                                    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                                    <option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                    <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
                                    <option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
                                    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                                    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                                    <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
                                    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                                    <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                                    <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
                                    <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
                                    <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
                                    <option value="Wallis &amp; Futana Is">Wallis &amp; Futana Is</option>
                                    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                                    <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
                                    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                                    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                                    </select>


                <p>Gender  <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male</p>
                            <p><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female</p>
                <p>Link Address:        <input type="text" name="link" size="60" value="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"></p>
                <p>Description of the link: <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="20" value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"></textarea></p>
                <p>Link Category 1  <select id="type1" name="type1" value="<?php echo $row['type1']; ?>" >
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <option value="Video">Video</option>
                                    <option value="Article">Article</option>
                                    <option value="Newspaper">Newspaper</option>
                                    <option value="Magazine">Magazine</option>
                                    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                                    <option value="Book">Book</option>
                                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                    </select></p>
                <p>Link Category 2  <select id="type2" name="type2" value="<?php echo $row['type2']; ?>">
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    <option value="Science">Science</option>
                                    <option value="Health">Health</option>
                                    <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                                    <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
                                    <option value="National News">National News</option>
                                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                                    <option value="Education">Education</option>
                                    </select></p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />                
                <p><input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Modify"> </p>

        </form> 
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $update1 ="update person set firstname='$_POST[fname]', lastname='$_POST[lname]',email='$_POST[email]',
                        telephone='$_POST[phone]',address='$_POST[address]',state='$_POST[state]',
                        country='$_POST[country]',sex='$_POST[gender]',where person_id=$_POST[id]";
            mysqli_query($conn,$update1) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "User had been modified!";
            header("Location: securequery1.php");


        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error shows that there was no username passed

```
" Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'linkyoutube'"
```

You are using mysqli_connect but then calling mysql_select_db afterwards, which is mysql not mysqli.  With your call to mysqli_connect you are already selecting the DB with the fourth parameter. I think you simply need to delete the line:-

```
mysql_select_db("linkyoutube");
```

Comment: When I click submit the page blinks no error is shown but the new data is not updated to the database. Any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: There is an error in the SQL - a comma before where.  Try removing the comma

eg 

sex='$_POST[gender]' where person_id=$_POST[id]